# Figure out Time Remaining in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Okay so the situation I am in is that I want to figure out exactly how many days are left until a specific date such as May 15, 2013. The date doesn't really matter but the idea is to figure out the amount of days left before reaching that day.

I thought of doing something like this (pseudo code):

```
y=$end_year-$cur_year

if [ y -ge 1 ]; then
   days=$y*365
else
     continue
fi

if [ $end_month -gt $cur_month ]; then
     m=$end_month-$cur_month
else
     contine
fi

if [ $end_day -gt $cur_day ]; then
    d=$end_day-$cur_day
else
    continue
fi

result=$days+$m+$d
```

Now i don't know if there is an easier way to do this because I am very new to Linux and shell scripting so if there is a better way to do it please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one calculates it from the difference of unix timestamps:

```
date
Fri Jul  6 15:04:04 BST 2012
echo $(( (`date -d "May 15, 2013" +'%s'` - `date +'%s'`) / (60*60*24) ))
312
```

Division is floored, so you have to add `1`, if a fraction day counts as a whole day.

Answer (score 1):

```
[06 Jul 2012 18:13:47] rush@home  ~
$ DIFF=$(( $(date -d '05/15/2013 00:00' +%s) - $(date +%s) )) ; \
  echo $(( DIFF / (3600*24) )) days $(( DIFF % (3600*24) / 3600 )) \
  hours $(( DIFF % 3600 / 60 )) minutes $(( DIFF % 60 )) seconds left
312 days 5 hours 46 minutes 13 seconds left
```